# Windows 10 Installation - Bitlocker Drive Encryption

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker, system-repair-disc

My windows 10 laptop went kaput and it doesn't reach the login screen anymore.

I tried the repair options - fixing the start up steps,etc but i get the message that it can not be fixed.

So i decided to re-install windows to repair the machine (I do not want to lose the data already on the laptop).

I reached the step where it asked me to select the partition for installation - however it does not let me select the SSD partition because it says it is Bitlocker encrypted.
[image]

So i went back to the repair options and tried the command line option
`c:\>manage-bde -off c:`
This resulted in an error: `the file or directory is corrupted or unreadable.`

So what are my options - is there a way i can recover this installation (without having to delete the partition). **My main aim is to recover my data on the disk.**

Comment: You will be unable to repair the installation until you decrypt the drive (disable BitLocker). Healthy installations do not suddenly become unbootable.  That cannot be done without the recovery key for the drive

Answer (score -1):

None of the diagnostic options were working, so i finally used the command prompt. Even a simple `DIR` on the C drive was failing.
The fix that worked for me required the following steps -

1. run `chkdsk` from the WinRE environment on C drive. As I had suspected, the MFT had got corrupt. The chkdsk fixed the errors.
2. Check the status of the bitlocker using the command `c:\>manage-bde -status c:`
3. Once the errors were fixed, I used the `robocopy` and got the files i wanted backed up to an external drive.
4. Used the command, `c:\>manage-bde -off c:` to turn off the encryption.
5. After the drive was completely decrypted, the installation was able to continue.

The Windows. old folder contains all the files and data from the previous  installation including the profiles

[image]

Comment: Your old user profiles should be contained within the Windows.old directory, but if that is the case, it entirely depends on what other actions you performed within the installation environment.  You cannot perform an in-place repair install of Windows unless you can boot to Windows.  I didn't mention anything of backing up your data since I thought you already knew that was the case.  I remove the unnecessary commentary from your answer.

Comment: @Ramhound: thanks for the edit. I wasn't sure at the end whether to delete the question or to leave an answer to it.